# Latex image at full page (removing any white border) and no page number

Tags: graphics, fullwidth, fullpage

I would like to load an image so that it is full page, without any white border. Something like [this](http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55246f40e4b08ad5c0f61a87/55f5a5c7e4b0ede8c0b787c4/55f5a653e4b0526d2c51cd02/1442884151864/?format=1000w). My code is like this (there may be some packages not required for this example)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{memoir}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pdfpages}    

\begin{document}
\chapter {Chapter1}
\begin{figure}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\includegraphics[width=1.6\textwidth]{Myimage}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But what i get is something like this, where the black area is what is covered by my image. As you can see, on the bottom left there is also the page number. I do not want the page number nor the white area on the top and on the left. How can do it?

[image: mypic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this,

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}


\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.south west)}]
\node[anchor=south west] (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{pig}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to implement your suggest on my example and it works, but it does not on my actual .tex file. This file is exactly equal to what reported in my example except that it is an appendix I recall from the main file using \input{myfile}. The result I have now is that the figure is located in the top right and just the bottom is visible. I did not see any error or warning

Comment: Never mind, it works now I have the images full page. Nevertheless, I still have the page number at the bottom left-right (because of the pagestyle). How can I remove them?

Comment: \thispagestyle{empty}